# How to read int from stdin but print text before?

Tags: ocaml, stdin

I need to ask the user to input an integer and save it in a variable. I can do this with `read_int`, but I can't display anything until the user has entered all the inputs I ask him to. Let me explain :

```ml
open Format


let ask_for_int name = 
    printf "%s?\n" name;
    let inp = read_int () in 
    printf "You have entered %d\n" inp; inp
;;


let () = printf "Hello World!\n"; 
    let myVar = ask_for_int "myVar" and myVar2 = ask_for_int "myVar2" in
    if myVar = 5 && myVar2 = 10 then printf "Ok\n" else printf "Wrong\n";;
```

I would like this program to output something like this:

```
Hello World!
myVar? 5
You have entered 5
myVar2? 10
You have entered 10
Ok
```

But for now, the only thing I get is

```
5
10
Hello World!
myVar?
You have entered 5
myVar2?
You have entered 10
Ok
```

And as long as the user has not entered all the inputs, nothing is displayed on the screen. Does anyone know how to do what I am looking for ?

Thanks

Comment: To add a couple of small points to the excellent answer–it's idiomatic to _not_ `open` modules as much as can be avoided, and instead just use the full scoped name e.g. `Printf.printf ...`. Also, you don't need `;;` in source code. That's only needed in the REPL (toplevel).

Comment: Got it, thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your partial output is being buffered (hence not displayed until later). You should get what you want if you change the first `printf` to this:

```
printf "%s? %!" name
```

The `%!` specifier asks to flush the output buffer at that point.

To see the other strings you need to flush at those later points also.

However, I wonder why you're using functions from the `Format` module. Unless your project has complicated requirements for the format of the output, you would probably be better off using the simpler `Printf` module. Since you're just using `printf`, the code will be the same. However the `Printf` module tries to be more interactive with its buffering. If you change `open Format` to `open Printf`, your code will work with almost no change (or at least it does for me). You still probably want to change `"%s?\n"` to `"%s? "`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works like a charm now. I was using `printf` from `Format` because I didn't know about the `Printf` module... Still learning Ocaml ;)